# Displaying the frequencies of randomly generated integers

Tags: c, random

This code is meant to list the number from 1-9 and display next to each number the frequency that it appears in the 10,000 random numbers that have been generated.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{
int counts[10];
int i;
int random;
srand(time(0));
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
counts[i] = 0;
for (i = 0; i<= 10000; i++)
{
random = (int)(10.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0));
counts[random]++;
}
for (i = 0; i<10; i++);
printf("%d occurs %f%%\n", i, i/100.0);
return(0);

}
```

However when I run the program I get a list from 1-9 which I want but next to it lists 1-9 but in decimal instead of the frequency. this is what i get when i run it:

```
1 occurs 0.010000%
2 occurs 0.020000%
3 occurs 0.030000%
4 occurs 0.040000%
5 occurs 0.050000%
6 occurs 0.060000%
7 occurs 0.070000%
8 occurs 0.080000%
9 occurs 0.090000%
```

What do i need to change in order to get the frequency of each number, 
also when I run the code from terminal using `emacs` it lists 1-9 but when I run the code in eclipse it only displays 10 occurs 0.100000% in the console. Is there any reason why this happens?

Comment: Look again at your code, especially what you're printing out.  If that does not work, debug it.  If that doesn't work, I give up.

Comment: "Why isn't my C code wroking properly?" - Because you failed to indent it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're storing the frequencies of each number correctly, you're just not displaying them.  Your output doesn't refer to the `counts` array at all.

In this line:

```
printf("%d occurs %f%%\n", i, i/100.0);
```

`i/100.0` should be `counts[i]/10000`.

Comment: when i changed that i get a warning saying: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat] and then when i continue i get this:                     1 occurs 0.000000%
    2 occurs 0.000000%
    3 occurs 0.000000%
    4 occurs 0.000000%
    5 occurs 0.000000%
    6 occurs 0.000000%
    7 occurs 0.000000%
    8 occurs 0.000000%
    9 occurs 0.000000%

Comment: @user1760250 You can either cast to double or divide by 10000.0 to get rid of the warning.  Also, try using `rand() % 10 + 1;` to generate a random number from 1 - 10.  If that doesn't work, print out the random values as you're generating them.  I don't have a C compiler in front of me, so I can't test your code.

Comment: i changed its to 10000.0 which got rid of the warning however i still get the same results even with the rand() % 10 + 1;

Comment: @user1760250 Try printing out just the values of `counts` to see what they are.

Comment: i just get:     `1495121456 occurs 0.000000%`
    `1495121456 occurs 0.000000%`
    `1495121456 occurs 0.000000%`
    `1495121456 occurs 0.000000%`
    `1495121456 occurs 0.000000%`
    `1495121456 occurs 0.000000%`
    `1495121456 occurs 0.000000%`
    `1495121456 occurs 0.000000%`
    `1495121456 occurs 0.000000%`

Comment: @user1760250 Print out each random value as you generate it to make sure they're between 1 and 10.  Also make sure your indenting is correct and that all of your variables are getting initialized correctly (use print statements again).

Comment: @user1760250 You have a semicolon at the end of the head of your last for loop.  Removing that should work.  http://ideone.com/E0hre

Comment: Also, delete the ';' after the last `for (i = 0; i<10; i++);`. The ';' is causing your `printf` to execute only once instead of 10 times.